# Why is renaming (rather than copying) the default way to create backup files?

Tags: backup

The documentation on backup file creation, [Copying vs. Renaming](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Copying.html#Backup-Copying), makes it sound like copying is the more sensible choice.

- file owner and group remain unchanged
- hard links remain associated with the actual file rather than its backup

Given that, why does the default behavior prefer renaming in most cases?

- `backup-by-copying` defaults to `nil`
- `backup-by-copying-when-linked` defaults to `nil`
- `backup-by-copying-when-mismatch` defaults to `t`

Comment: This probably relates to how some file-systems treat copying and renaming. Some file-systems may use file-level deduplication, in which case no new data will be written in case of renaming, but will in case of copying... (this is just a guess). But then this isn't really very useful for backups... I think, it's best not to rely on defaults and choose the strategy after reading file-system documentation.

Comment: I guess for efficiency: copying has to write the file contents twice, renaming only once (see docstring of `make-backup-files`).